# Merge two matrix by column names and row names

Tags: r

I want to merge the two matrices according to the column names and row names.

The values in both matrices are numeric, and the merger is to average the two matrices that have appeared together.

matrix1:

```
  A B C 
x 1 4 3
z 5 2 4
k 1 2 3
```

and matrix2:

```
  A B C D
x 6 4 1 2
y 2 3 1 3
z 1 4 1 4 
k 7 5 3 1
```

so the output will be:

```
   A   B   C  D
x 3.5  4   2  2
y  2   3   1  3
z  3   3  2.5 4
k  4  3.5  3  1
```

My idea is to use for loop or `apply` function, but if the matrices are big, then this program will run for a long time. Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rownames` and `colnames` to subset `matrix2` and update only part of it.

```
matrix2[rownames(matrix1), colnames(matrix1)] <- (matrix1 + matrix2[rownames(matrix1), colnames(matrix1)])/2

matrix2

#    A   B   C D
#x 3.5 4.0 2.0 2
#y 2.0 3.0 1.0 3
#z 3.0 3.0 2.5 4
#k 4.0 3.5 3.0 1
```

**data**

```
matrix1 <- structure(c(1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Dim = c(3L, 
           3L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "z", "k"), c("A", "B", "C")))

matrix2 <- structure(c(6L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y", "z", 
"k"), c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
```